# what if we link both same name variable with different data type?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, ld

I have tried below code foo1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(void);
int x = 38;
int y = 39;

int main() {
f();
printf("x = %d\n", x);
printf("y = %d\n", y);
return 0;
}
```

foo2.c

```
double x;

void f() {
x = 42.0;
}
```

output:

```
$ gcc -o myprog foo1.c foo2.c
$ ./myprog
x = 0
y = 1078263808
```

i got weird output for this code can some one explain how it will come?

Comment: The behaviour of this program is [undefined](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Also please don't post images of code.

Comment: @n.m. ok i changed in the code thanks for suggesting

Comment: When you lie to your compiler, it will get its own back by not doing what you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In foo1.c you have two variables x and y each having 4 bytes totally 8 bytes. In foo2.c you are having x variable as double.

While execution x in foo1 (4 bytes) is replaced by x in foo2 (8 bytes). Ultimately memory of x & y (totally 8 bytes) in foo1 is overwritten by x in foo2 (8 bytes).

1078263808 value is floating point representation of 42 in double.

NOTE: x & y memories in foo1 are successive.

Comment: i little got you but still confusing in why x=0 and y=1078263808 ? can explain in details?  i didn't get this line "1078263808 value is floating point representation of 42 in double." ! @Rajeshkumar

Comment: this is a very clear answer. to enforce it you may generate a map file to demonstrate the respective position of x and y. More over you can make another small program to show that 42.0 (double) is encoded in 1078263808 by casting (printf("%ld\n" (int) (42.0)).